# SwiftUI Preview displays error - Cannot preview in this file -- current target needs adjusted build settings

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, xcode11.1

I'm using Xcode 11.1 and all of my swift previews show the following errors:

[image: swiftui preview pane error]

> Cannot preview in this file -- current target needs adjusted build settings

along with

> "ProjectTests.xctest' failed to get build
>   settings:
>   unsupportedProductType("com.apple.product-type.bundle.unit-test", <Xc..."

Clicking the diagnostics button generates the following popup:

[image]

> Open file has supported build settings
>   "ProjectTests.xctest" failed to get build settings: unsupportedProductType("com.apple.product-type.bundle.unit-test", <Xcode3TargetProduct:0xblahblahblahProjectTests.xctest blueprint:< Xcode3Target:0xblahblahProjectTests>>)

My previews still render fine, but is there some way to remove this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error no longer exists in Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52).

Comment: The error still exists in XCode Version 11.3 (11C29)

Answer (score 2):

Change Destination to some Simulator instead of "iOS Generic Device" or in preview provider specify preview device explicitly, like

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        .previewDevice("iPhone 11")
    }
}
```

**Xcode Version 11.1 (11A1027)**

Comment: Thanks @Asperi! I have tried both `.previewLayout(.device)` and `.previewDevice("iPhone 11")` as well as choosing a specific device rather than "Generic iOS Device" and haven't noticed a change.